# Combine two windows with tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I have just started playing with tkinter today and I have two bit of code I have been playing with as examples however I am struggling to combine these can anyone advise. I would like to clock to display in the main window.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import sys
import time


root = Tk()
root.title('Logging')
Label(text='Time logging').pack(side=TOP,padx=100,pady=100)

entry = Entry(root, width=25)
entry.pack(side=TOP,padx=25,pady=25)

def onok():
    x, y = entry.get().split('x')
    for row in range(int(y)):
        for col in range(int(x)):
            print((col, row))

Button(root, text='Log Time', command=onok).pack(side=LEFT)
Button(root, text='CLOSE').pack(side= RIGHT)

def tick():
    global time1
    # get the current local time from the PC
    time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    # if time string has changed, update it
    if time2 != time1:
        time1 = time2
        clock.config(text=time2)
        # calls itself every 200 milliseconds
        # to update the time display as needed
        # could use >200 ms, but display gets jerky
    clock.after(200, tick)

root = Tk()
time1 = ''

status = Label(root, text="v1.0", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
status.grid(row=10, column=10)

clock = Label(root, font=('times', 20, 'bold'), bg='green')
clock.grid(row=0, column=1) 

tick()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Frame` to group clock widgets and use `grid` inside this frame. And frame you can put in main window. (And you don't need second `Tk()`)

I put it at the top but you can choose other place.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

# --- functions ---

def on_ok():
    x, y = entry.get().split('x')
    for row in range(int(y)):
        for col in range(int(x)):
            print((col, row))

def tick():
    global time1

    # get the current local time from the PC
    time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    # if time string has changed, update it
    if time2 != time1:
        time1 = time2
        clock.config(text=time2)
        # calls itself every 200 milliseconds
        # to update the time display as needed
        # could use >200 ms, but display gets jerky
    clock.after(200, tick)

# --- main window ---

time1 = ''

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Logging')

# add frame in main window (root)

other = tk.Frame(root)
other.pack()

# put widgets in frame (other)

status = tk.Label(other, text="v1.0", bd=1, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W)
status.grid(row=10, column=10)

clock = tk.Label(other, font=('times', 20, 'bold'), bg='green')
clock.grid(row=0, column=1) 

# put other widget directly in main widnow (root)

tk.Label(root, text='Time logging').pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=100, pady=100)

entry = tk.Entry(root, width=25)
entry.pack(side=tk.TOP, padx=25, pady=25)

tk.Button(root, text='Log Time', command=on_ok).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(root, text='CLOSE', command=root.destroy).pack(side= tk.RIGHT)

tick()

# --- start ---

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different root windows. Use one root = Tk() line at the top and you should have them on the same page.

Comment: I thought this, but removing one gives me the following error;

Comment: Yes, you cannot use .pack and .grid at the same time on the children of root. Try changing all your pack to grids or all your grids to pack and see what i mean.

Comment: Check [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) out. It explains all the finer details of using grid. if you notice, there's a big warning in the middle in green explaining my above comment.

Comment: Thank, that page is really helpful